# Rewrite URL with multiple parameters php

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I have page redirect URL like below with more than one parameters.

http://example.com/search.php?layout=details&Keyword=mobile&view=product&CategoryId=1026&product_id=93477

From that URL i'm taking all parameter values to take a data from database.

So when i load this page i need to show URL most user friendly like below. In that URL should contain only the value of product_id which is i'm using my redirect URL

http://example.com/93477.htm

I have tried to rewrite this URL like below. But in that i couldn't use the parameters "categoryId" and "keyword"

rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+).htm /search.php?layout=details&view=product&Keyword=$3&CategoryId=$2&product_id=$1 last;

Please anyone help me to done it successfully..

Regards,

VIGNESH KUMAR K

Comment: If each of the parameters in the querystring of the original url are used to help build an sql query then without them you will not find the same records. Each required parameter in the original url should be mapped in the rewrittern url

Answer (score 1):

Try this mate ,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/search\.php\?layout=details&Keyword=([^&]*)&view=product&CategoryId=([^&]*)&product_id=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3/%1? [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?layout=details&Keyword=$2&view=product&CategoryId=$3&product_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**The original URL:**

> http://example.com/search.php?layout=details&Keyword=mobile&view=product&CategoryId=1026&product_id=93477

**The rewritten URL:**

> http://example.com/93477.htm

**Update 1 :**

> [QSA] has been added in the above code now so that to append the query string in order to retrive
>   dynamic parameters using PHP $_GET

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

**Update 2:**

> Edited the .htaccess code to make Keyword and CategoryId Dynamic

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But in that the original URL the CategoryId and Keyword will change dynamically for every URL. So in that case shall we use your code for it.

Comment: use [QSA] to get the query string attached  . let me update the answer hold on mate

Comment: @VigneshKumar updated the code , check and update me whether it solves your problem mate ?